# Building mysqli queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

say if I have the query `select users.user_id, users.fname, users.lname, bios.bio, groups.groupid from users LEFT JOIN bios on users.user_id = bios.userid` then I want to add another table on a condition then add a `where` statement at the end. The problem is because when I bind the param it said 'number of variables doesn't match the number of variables in the prepare statement'. How would I solve this? Cheers. Example:

```
    $info = "select users.user_id, users.fname, users.lname, bios.bio, groups.groupid from users LEFT JOIN bios on users.user_id = bios.userid";
    $content = $members->prepare($info);
    if ($_GET['where'] == 'requests') $info .= "LEFT JOIN requests on users.user_id = requests.receiver";
    else if ($_GET['where'] == 'referrals') $info .= "LEFT JOIN referrals on users.user_id = referrals.receiver";
    $info .= "where users.user_id = ?";
    $content->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['token'][1]);
    $content->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the SQL string after preparing it.  Don't do that.  Do it like this instead:

```
$info = "select users.user_id, users.fname, users.lname, bios.bio, groups.groupid from users LEFT JOIN bios on users.user_id = bios.userid";
if ($_GET['where'] == 'requests') $info .= " LEFT JOIN requests on users.user_id = requests.receiver";
else if ($_GET['where'] == 'referrals') $info .= " LEFT JOIN referrals on users.user_id = requests.receiver";
$info .= " where users.user_id = ?";
$content = $members->prepare($info);
$content->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['token'][1]);
$content->execute();
```

Edit: Also, make sure your SQL fragments are separated with spaces where necessary; the `.=` operator *doesn't* automatically add a space for you.